# Deleting orphaned .msp and .dll files

Tags: files, windows-registry

I have two terminal servers that I need to clear room off of. I have 35.8gb of .dll's and 15.5gb of .msp's. I need to clear these en masse, as there are literally thousands of files that I would have to manually go through and check otherwise. Does anyone have a script/program/suggestion on what to do to remove these files?

Answer (score 0):

```
del *.msp, *.dll /s
```

Note that deleting DLL files en masse is likely to break the server unless these DLL's are in a specific directory and aren't being used by Windows or any applications. Target the command to the specific directory where these unwanted files exist.

Comment: I need something that compares what is on the computer vs what is in the registry, and deletes the .msps and dlls that are not in the registry